# How to set caching policy in RESTkit 0.2

Tags: ios, restkit

I'm unclear how to use the RESTKit 0.2 API to set the caching policy.  I have a request that is being rerun every time I open the app, but I would like it to be cached.  How do I set the caching policy to always cache the request?

**Update**
I learned that RestKit will automatically cache Core Data backed Mappings.

Comment: Hey @deepwinter, where did you learn that the RestKit will automatically cache Core Data backed mappings?  If true, that is fantastic but I am looking to verify it.  Thanks!

Comment: If you use RKEntityMapping instead of RKObjectMapping this is the default behavior - because the deserialization creates Core Data objects and saves them.  http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKEntityMapping.html  Enjoy!  It's a great system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caching is controlled by the [RKObjectRequestOperation](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/RestKit/0.24.0/Classes/RKObjectRequestOperation.html) class. Check the 'Caching' section of the documentation.

Comment: looks the link is expired, is it still true in 0.25 now? I want to enable ETag header in Restkit. For `NSMutableURLRequest `, I can use `NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy` to enable it, but how to enable it in Restkit?

Comment: @ybbaigo If the server uses ETags they will be respected by default

Comment: You are right, I just got confused by FLEX debug information, thank your very much.