# How to manage Caching for RESTKit v0.23.1

Tags: ios, caching, restkit

I am using RESTKit v0.23.1 from cocoapods. The problem is sometime when I send a get request, the results are not the updated copy as compare to the one I get from browser. Tested on Simulator is OK, but always hit by the problem when running in iPhone 4. Thus I am suspecting there is some caching policy wasn't set properly?

So far search through the net, the closest I can find is [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16095599/how-to-set-caching-policy-in-restkit-0-2?rq=1), however it would be better to have code example to show how to achieve it.

Following is my typical get request used throughout the app.

```
 [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:path
                                       parameters:param
                                          success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                                          } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                          }];
```

**Update** - 20140716

I had tried the following methods:

1) subclass RKObjectManager - Not Working

```
- (NSMutableURLRequest *)requestWithObject:(id)object
                                method:(RKRequestMethod)method
                                  path:(NSString *)path
                            parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [super requestWithObject:object method:method path:path parameters:parameters];
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData;
    return request;
}
```

2) suggested by Sandro Machado - Not Working

```
  [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
```

New Finding is that request time is 0 second when i second time send Get request

```
2014-07-16 18:39:45.319 LoveByteTest[1203:942b] I restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:220 
    GET 'http://xx-api.xxx.us/xx/xx/comments?auth_token=xxxx&commentable_id=1234&commentable_type=photo' (200 OK / 3 objects) 
    [request=0.0000s mapping=0.0217s total=0.0914s]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:  `[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];`

Comment: It is not an elegant solution but you can try to add timestamp as query parameter to force cache refresh.

Something like: "http://example.com/myrequest?rand=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

Answer (score 0):

add a no-cache cache-control header to the response

it fixes the caching problem without hacking the client-side